# Cannot purge graphical interface from lubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, lightdm, lxde, lxqt

I installed lubuntu 18.04, so I wanna purge graphical interface, to make it run as a server, with just CLI enabled. But I can't!!

I already did:

```
sudo apt remove --purge lubuntu-*
sudo apt remove --purge lxde*
sudo apt remove --purge lxqt*
```

But it is starting with graphical interface with lightdm login screen.

Any ideas about how to get it?

Comment: Remove lightdm....

Comment: It worked, @user535733! So obvious, but you deserve answer reputation. Write an answer, I will vote on it